# How to get Tweet from date x to date y

Tags: python-3.x, nltk, tweepy

```
def search_for_a_tweet(bearer_token, query,D1,D2):

    url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json"
    formed_url ='?screen_name='+query+'&count=300&fromDate=D1&toDate=D2'

search_results = search_for_a_tweet(bearer_token,'TOIIndiaNews','201808060000','201808070000')
```

Here I get only current date tweet.
Help me for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the search API instead : https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets.html

To get tweets from a specific user within a period, the `q` parameter will be for example :

```
q=from:user since:2018-08-15 until:2018-08-18
```

(urlencode the query before to send it).

But with public API you will get only last 7 days.
So you can perform the query on the official Twitter web site :

https://twitter.com/search?f=tweets&vertical=default&q=from%3Arealdonaldtrump%20since%3A2018-08-15%20until%3A2018-08-17

Comment: But using API we can get only limited tweets. Is it right?

Comment: plz reply as soon as possible

Comment: what do you mean by "limited tweets" ? with the public API you won't get tweets older than 7 days, unless you use the premium API.